# asp mvc 5 using webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I have started learning webApi in Mvc5.

I tried my first project but unfortunately it doesn't work and I can't understand why.

i have done these steps:

1- At first I created a database named Person in sql server

2- Then I added a table named Person with these fields: Id as primary key and FullName

3- I made an Empty MVC project is vs 2013

4- I added my EF model and rebuilt the project

5- I created a new Folder named api

6- I added a controller (Web Api 2 with Actions, using Entity Framework):

[image]

7- I added these lines to Global.asax

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;
```

8 - And here is my Application-start:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

But When I run the application and I enter `http://localhost:XXXX/api/people` into the url browser can't find the resource.

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance

And here is PeopleController:

```
public class PeopleController : ApiController
{
    private PersonEntities db = new PersonEntities();

    // GET api/People
    public IQueryable<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return db.People;
    }

    // GET api/People/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Person))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPerson(int id)
    {
        Person person = db.People.Find(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(person);
    }

    // PUT api/People/5
    public IHttpActionResult PutPerson(int id, Person person)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != person.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!PersonExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST api/People
    [ResponseType(typeof(Person))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostPerson(Person person)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.People.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = person.Id }, person);
    }

    // DELETE api/People/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Person))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeletePerson(int id)
    {
        Person person = db.People.Find(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.People.Remove(person);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(person);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool PersonExists(int id)
    {
        return db.People.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code for PeopleController

Comment: @Claies I edited the post and added PeopleController.

Comment: @Claies can you please help  me? I really need it

Comment: and if you use the URL `http://localhost:XXXX/people` ?

Comment: /People by itself will not work because of the default web api routing, if you want that to work you would have to change the default

Comment: @blubbiedevis No, It doesn't work

Comment: read over the web api reference.. might help http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Heeey, I found something!! You should right click on your proect and set as start up project. As the pic says you are running Bundle

Comment: Additionally, you were doing a GET against ./api/people which doesn't match any routes defined in your controller, thus IMO resulting in the 404.  I would expect this to return a list of people if you were to implement it.